# While Loop to Iterate through Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if someone could help me with creating a while loop to iterate through several databases to obtain data from one table from two columns.  this is was I have done so far.  nothing works because i do not know how to make the select statement work through each database with regards to the table that I am querying from each database (dbo.tbldoc)

```
DECLARE @Loop int
DECLARE @DBName varchar(300)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(255)

SET @Loop = 1
SET @DBName = ''

   WHILE @Loop = 1
BEGIN

   SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases 
   WHERE [name] like 'z%' and create_date between '2010-10-17' and '2011-01-15'
   ORDER BY [name]

      SET @Loop = @@ROWCOUNT

   IF @Loop = 0
      BREAK

   SET @SQL = ('USE ['+ @DBNAME +']')
      IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM sys.tables WHERE name != 'dbo.tbldoc' )
                  BEGIN
               SELECT SUM(PGCOUNT), CREATED FROM **dbo.tbldoc**
            END
            ELSE
            --BEGIN
               PRINT 'ErrorLog'
            END
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would consider [sp_MSForEachDB](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sp_MSForEachDB) which is a lot easier...

Edit:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'USE [?]; IF DB_NAME() LIKE ''Z%%''
BEGIN


END
'
```

Comment: doesn't this bring up all databases?  i am only querying databases beginning with 'Z'

Comment: Yes, it is, but you should insert data resulted in the upper code in a table and filter after that by db name.

Comment: This (and the analogous sp_MSForEachTable) work wonderfully but keep in mind there is a limit of 128 characters in the command piece of this.

Comment: Great answer, a useful addition for anyone having trouble getting there head around the above for their own soultion the following article is very useful:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/

Comment: The filter (like Z) will not work because DB_NAME() will always return `master`. You need to call `USE ?` beforehand. E.g.: `sp_MSForEachDB 'USE ? print db_name()'`.

Comment: @FFFffff well spotted from 9 years ago! Fixed

Answer (score 4):

My code to search for data from more than one database would be:

```
use [master]
go
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#database') is not null 
    drop TABLE #database
go

create TABLE #database(id INT identity primary key, name sysname)
go

set nocount on
insert into #database(name)

select name
from sys.databases
where name like '%tgsdb%' --CHANGE HERE THE FILTERING RULE FOR YOUR DATABASES!
and source_database_id is null
order by name

select *
from #database

declare @id INT, @cnt INT, @sql NVARCHAR(max), @currentDb sysname;

select @id = 1, @cnt = max(id)
from #database
while @id <= @cnt

BEGIN
    select @currentDb = name
    from #database
    where id = @id
    set @sql = 'select Column1, Column2 from ' + @currentDb + '.dbo.Table1'
    print @sql
    exec (@sql);
    print '--------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    set @id = @id + 1;
END
go
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(dbname sysname NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SumPGCOUNT INT,
CREATED DATETIME)

DECLARE @Script NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @Script = @Script + '

USE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(''dbo.tbldoc''))
  INSERT INTO #T
  SELECT db_name() AS dbname, SUM(PGCOUNT) AS SumPGCOUNT, CREATED 
  FROM dbo.tbldoc
  GROUP BY CREATED;  
  '
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE state=0 AND user_access=0 and has_dbaccess(name) = 1
 AND [name] like 'z%' and create_date between '2010-10-17' and '2011-01-15'
ORDER BY [name]

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
 BEGIN
 --PRINT @Script
 EXEC (@Script)
 SELECT * FROM #T
 END

 DROP TABLE #T
```

Comment: I get this error when I run your script: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'dbo.tbldoc.Created' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Ah I just pasted in your original query. I guess you need a `GROUP BY` in there then.

Comment: when i do group by created, it states that the column does not exist.  the column is a column of the tbldoc table.

Comment: so far so good, how can I can add within if exists, that if the pgcount column in the database tbdldoc table isn't >0, it should be skipped.  i don't want to query a table that doesn't have a value in this column.  i want to skip it.

Comment: You can't without looking at the table itself so you might as well add `HAVING SUM(PGCOUNT)>0` If you don't want the empty result sets being returned change the query to insert into a temp table rather than select directly then just select from that at the end.

Comment: to do this I would do the following: CREATE TABLE #TEMPIMGCOUNTER
(DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
TOTAL_IMAGES INT,
IMG_DATE_UPLOAD DATETIME                                                                                                                                 then insert this code right under the if exists statement:                                                           INSERT INTO #TEMPIMGCOUNTER (DBNAME, TOTAL_IMAGES, IMG_DATE_UPLOAD)

Comment: then:                                                         SELECT  DBNAME, SUM(TOTAL_IMAGES) AS TOTAL_IMAGES, convert(NVARCHAR(10), IMG_DATE_UPLOAD, 101) AS IMG_DATE_UPLOAD FROM #TEMPIMGCOUNTER
    GROUP BY DBNAME, IMG_DATE_UPLOAD
    ORDER BY IMG_DATE_UPLOAD                                                                                                                          when I do this they do not add up creating one entry for each database.

Comment: Yep that's the general idea. You've never explained the results you need though so I can't tell you how to get there!

Comment: I need to have totals of the images for each database by date.  What I am getting are totals with the dates repeating.  I tried using distinct, but that did not work.

Comment: @Jeff - You need to use `GROUP BY DBNAME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), IMG_DATE_UPLOAD, 101)` You can't refer to an alias in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: and the database name repeats.

Comment: i will try your suggestion and see what happens.  thank you, i will update you asap.

Comment: it worked...thank you so much...i just have to figure out a way to make it run faster.

Comment: do you by chance know how I can apply this in vb.net?  I want to generate reports using this script that you helped me with.  Is there a book or website that I can use or do you know how to translate this code into vb.net?

Comment: You could create a stored procedure with this code then call it via ADO.NET you could also consider using the report viewer control. If this answer resolved your question you should mark this as the accepted answer rather than the hidden cursor one everyone else seems to like!

Comment: do you know of an additional statement that allows the above query to connect to other servers to run the query?  i want to add a command to connect to other servers and then run the above query.

Comment: You would need to set these up as linked servers.

Comment: is there a command for this?  for databases for example: USE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '...is there anything like this to connect to other servers.

Comment: i linked the servers, what is my next step?

Comment: I used this solution.  For future users, I would try to move all the "EXISTS" logic into the WHERE clause.  There were some false positives when moving a bunch of IF EXISTS logic in the @Script that caused "Invalid Column Name" errors for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Loop int
DECLARE @MaxLoop int
DECLARE @DBName varchar(300)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @Loop = 1
SET @DBName = ''

set nocount on
SET @MaxLoop =  (select count([name]) FROM sys.databases where [name] like 'Z%')
WHILE @Loop <= @MaxLoop
    BEGIN
        SET @DBName = (select TableWithRowsNumbers.name from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by [name]) as Row,[name] FROM sys.databases where [name] like 'Z%' ) TableWithRowsNumbers where Row = @Loop)
        SET @SQL = 'USE [' + @DBName + ']'
        exec (@SQL)
        ...
        ...
        set @Loop = @Loop + 1
    END
```

***Note: I didn't add the check if exists here.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing one last week on the fly for some stuff I was doing.

Blog post here:

http://tsells.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/sql-server-database-iterator/

Here is the code.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
use master
go

Declare
@dbname nvarchar(500),
@variable1 int,
@variable2 int,
@variable3 int,
@totaldb int = 0,
@totaldbonserver int = 0,
@totaldbwithmatches int = 0

-- Get non system databases
Declare mycursor CURSOR for select name, database_id from SYS.databases where database_id > 4 order by name desc

open mycursor

fetch next from mycursor into @dbname, @variable1

while (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
        Declare @mysql nvarchar(500) = 'select @variable2OUT = COUNT(*) from [' + @dbname + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where Upper(TABLE_NAME) like ''MyTable''';
        SET @ParmDefinition = N'@variable2OUT int OUTPUT'
        set @totaldbonserver = @totaldbonserver + 1
        Execute sp_executesql @mysql, @ParmDefinition, @variable2 OUTPUT            

        if @variable2 = 1
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ParmDefinition2 NVARCHAR(500)
            Declare @mysql2 nvarchar(500) = 'select @variable2OUT = COUNT(*) from [' + @dbname + '].dbo.MyTable';
            SET @ParmDefinition2 = N'@variable2OUT int OUTPUT'
            Execute sp_executesql @mysql2, @ParmDefinition2, @variable3 OUTPUT
            set @totaldb = @totaldb + 1

            if @variable3 > 1
            BEGIN
                Print @dbname + ' matched the criteria'
                set @totaldbwithmatches = @totaldbwithmatches + 1
            END
            ELSE
            Select 1
        END    

        fetch next from mycursor into @dbname, @variable1
    END
    PRINT 'Total databases on server: '
    Print @totaldbonserver

    PRINT 'Total databases tested () : '
    Print @totaldb

    PRINT 'Total databases with matches: '
    Print @totaldbwithmatches
CLOSE mycursor
DEALLOCATE mycursor
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use a loop.  Hope this helps!

Note that "TABLE_OWNER" is that same as "SCHEMA Owner" and "TABLE_TYPE" will identify if the item is a table OR view.

```
--This will return all tables, table owners and table types for all database(s) that are NOT 'Offline'
--Offline database information will not appear

Declare @temp_table table(
DB_NAME varchar(max),
TABLE_OWNER varchar(max),
TABLE_NAME varchar(max),
TABLE_TYPE varchar(max),
REMARKS varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @temp_table (DB_NAME, TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE,REMARKS)

EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC sp_tables'

SELECT DB_NAME, TABLE_OWNER, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE 
FROM @temp_table 
--Uncomment below if you are seaching for 1 database
--WHERE DB_NAME = '<Enter specific DB Name>'

--For all databases other than 'System Databases'
WHERE DB_NAME not in ('master','model','msdn','tempdb')
order by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't have to use a "USE DATABASE" statement. You can select from the particular database table by using a 3 part identifier as in:

select * from MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable

Comment: how can I create the 3 part identifier?  example: dbname.dbo.tbldoc  I want to select the pgcount column and created column from this table from all the databases.

Comment: You don't create a 3 part identifier, you just use it. To plug it in to what you have, you'd probably have to use some dynamic sql. It may indeed be easier to use sp_MSForEachDB - just check your output because I've seen that proc exclude some databases before.

Comment: This answer is not solving the issue. The while point is to get the table names and not knowing the names! What if you have 300 tables? whould you duplicate this command 300 times???